# HTML5 and CSS based mobile website

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I am creating a mobile website using HTML5 and CSS. How do I adjust to different devices? Either based on the device type(android/ios/windows/bb using navigator.userAgent) or based on screen width (using media queries).

Which practice is best and will be efficient?

I need to run my website on devices as follows:

- BB 6.0 and above,
- IOS 4.0 and above,
- Windows 8
- Android 4.0 and above.

Which is the best method?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! Please make sure to format your questions well and use proper grammar. See this help page: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Current best practice is a strategy called responsive design. It adjusts the website to match the width of your browser.

See Links

- [State of Responsive Design | Smashing Magazine](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/29/the-state-of-responsive-web-design/)
- [Adapting to Responsive Design | Smashing Mazine](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/18/adapting-to-a-responsive-design-case-study/)
- [Responsive Web Design Guidelines and Tutorials | Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/)